# Parent and Child Class creation in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, parent-child

I searched for all possible solutions but mostly out there are very basic print statements. Hence requesting help.

I am calling a CSV file from an S3 bucket location in all my scripts which does some formatting. So I want to create a parent class to mention the file name and bucket location. Which then I want to use the parent class in all the scipts. Please advise how to create.

The below script is not working. However, you will get an idea of what I am trying to achive

**Parent script** -

> I am not expecting this to run by itself hence did not include any
> import statements. Or am I supposed to add the import statements such
> as import pandas as pd, import io and import boto3

-Created format.ipynb and added below python code

```
class format (object):

def init

obj2 = s3.Bucket('bucketname').Object('foldername/filename.csv').get()

format_df = pd.read_csv(obj2['Body'], index_col=0)
```

**Main Script**

```
import pandas as pd      
import io
import boto3
import format from format (assuming this is how to call the parent class)

merge_df = pd.merge(format_df, anotherfile_df, how='left', left_on=['column heading'], right_on=['column heading'])
```

Comment: Hi - Welcome to stack overflow! Please see this guide to creating a [mre] - note specifically that your format.ipynb code does not work and it's not clear how you're importing from the notebook. Also, please post any error messages including the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when seeking debugging help. As it is, it's hard to tell what your issue really is.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want the class to do or how you expect to use (or need) it.

Comment: also note - importing an object from a module uses the syntax `from MODULE_NAME import OBJECT`, but also that `format` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format), so don't use it as a class name. You could call your class `Formatter` or something to use python's [style conventions (PEP8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiate class in Python you can do so like this:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name):
        # constructor logic
        self.first_name = first_name
```

In your main file to instantiate your class:

```py
person = Person("Bob")
```